# Boosting current to trigger 3v relay

Tags: transistors, led, gpio, nodemcu

I should start off by saying that I'm really new to this electronics engineering thing and I really have no idea what I'm doing.

I am working on building a display stand that turns some LEDs on/off over wifi/alexa. To do this, I am using a NodeMCU since it has an onboard ESP2866.

I am having an issue getting the GPIO pin on the NodeMCU to trip the relay. It's a 3v relay, so it should work. I tested this with an Arduino Nano and everything is working as expected. The only difference is that the NodeMCU outputs 3.3v@12mA on it's GPIO pins and the the Arduino Nano outputs 5v@40mA. I'm guessing my issue is that there is not enough current.

In order to boost the current, I "think" I need to use a transistor. I happen to have a BC547 handy and from what I understand it will boost the current. I'm just not sure how to wire it. Would one of you be willing to e-hold my hand and help me wire this correctly? or tell me this wont work if I'm going about it the wrong way? Here's how I currently have it wired.

[image: wiring diagram]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0VtIV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- The relay [datasheet](https://voron.ua/files/pdf/relay/JQC-3F(T73).pdf) - I have the 3VDC version from [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07L1GT3PL)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100669/discussion-on-question-by-travisballard-boosting-current-to-trigger-3v-relay). Any conclusions reached should be edited back into the question and/or any answer(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try and keep this on-point (yeah, I know, when has that ever happened?) Let me summarize details so that others don't have to suffer so much:

- MCU \$V_\text{CC}=3.3\:\text{V}\$
- Battery power supply: discharged at \$V_{\text{BAT}_\text{MIN}}=7.2\:\text{V}\$ and fully charged at \$V_{\text{BAT}_\text{MAX}}=8.4\:\text{V}\$
- 20 LEDs all driven either **ON** or **OFF** -- no animation required -- under MCU software control
- (5) BC547's available for the project
- This [relay](https://voron.ua/files/pdf/relay/JQC-3F(T73).pdf) available for the project
- LED voltage range: \$3.0\:\text{V}-3.2\:\text{V}\$
- LED design current: \$15\:\text{mA}-18\:\text{mA}\$

It helps, if you can accept the trade-offs (unstated for now), if you are able to "stack" (place in series) your LEDs. While you could use a "dropping resistor" for each LED, it's a more efficient use of your power supply if you can place them in series and use a smaller resistor for managing the current though them. The price you pay is poorer current regulation. But with a battery, I think most of scale tilts towards putting them in series, where possible.

So the first thing you want to do is work out how many (we already know only 2) LEDs can be strung together. Assuming they require at most \$3.2\:\text{V}\$, it's easy to see that two of them will probably work fine in series. That only means \$6.4\:\text{V}\$ total (worst case) and the battery is good for it.

To compute the resistor, I think we want to make sure we don't exceed the worst case current limit of \$18\:\text{mA}\$, when the battery is fresh and in the case where the LEDs present their *minimum* voltage of \$3.0\:\text{V}\$, each. To do that,  \$R=\frac{8.4\:\text{V}-2\cdot 3.0\:\text{V}}{18\:\text{mA}}= 133\:\Omega\$. Nearby values of \$120\:\Omega\$ or \$150\:\Omega\$ would be fine.

So this means you will string two LEDs (arranged so that they conduct in the ***same*** direction) and add one resistor, also in series. Three parts in such a series "string." Then you will do this 10 times, so that there are 30 parts together to make up 10 independent resistor+LED-pair strings. These strings have two ends and these ends are all connected so that you have 10 parallel strings. This makes up the entire "light system" -- itself appearing as just one component to the rest of the circuit.

Now, before I follow through with this line of thought, it's a good time to pause. This has been designed so that the worst case, per string, is \$18\:\text{mA}\$. But there are 10 strings. So we have to consider handling up to \$180\:\text{mA}\$ with either the relay (which can easily handle it) or with the BC547 (which cannot do so, by itself.)

Also, while the relay datasheet is sparse it suggests up to \$I_\text{COIL}=\frac{450\:\text{mW}}{3.0\:\text{V}}=150\:\text{mA}\$.

So it's almost like the phrase, "six of one, half-dozen of the other." Both the worst case coil current and the worst case total LED light's current are not far apart from each other. And, sadly, the BC547 just isn't designed for either of these currents.

Oh, well.

And still more. To saturate the BC547 so that it operates like a switch, the base current should be on the order of a tenth of the collector current that is being handled. Here, that's either \$15\:\text{mA}\$ or \$18\:\text{mA}\$ -- yet your I/O is rated (I read from you) at \$12\:\text{mA}\$.

But I think you'll be fine. The "tenth" rule isn't a law. And it is very likely the BC547 will saturate well enough at less base drive current. So I think that means we'll just "buy it" and assume that \$12\:\text{mA}\$ from the I/O pin will be sufficient.

There is another small issue -- what exactly is the voltage at the I/O pin when it is sourcing \$12\:\text{mA}\$? Since I don't have that information handy, I'm just going to assume that it is \$2.8\:\text{V}\$ and call it a day.

We still have to decide between the relay and directly driving the LEDs -- either case using at least two BJTs to get there. I'm just going to tell you to use the relay and switch the relay with the BJTs. Several reasons. One is that you have the relay and may want to learn by using it. Another is that it requires less current to operate and also it can switch \$1\:\text{A}\$, which is a lot more current and more useful if you later want to add more. And there is one final reason: trying to share current between two BJTs requires some voltage overhead at the emitter end in order to achieve it. And you don't have that much to play with, really, when using the BJTs to directly operate the LED strings.

Current sharing with BJTs means (usually) reserving out about \$500\:\text{mV}\$ for their emitter resistors. With \$75\:\text{mA}\$ for each BJT, this works out towards the standard value of \$6.8\:\Omega\$. The base hopefully will be nearer \$1.3\:\text{V}\$ (thereabouts), then. And if the I/O pin may droop to about \$2.8\:\text{V}\$, I computed the base resistor of \$120\:\Omega\$ as satisfactory.

Here's a suggestion for you, now:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBvceR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Yes, I added your \$10\:\text{k}\Omega\$ resistor!

A final note. Sacrificing some voltage at the BJT emitters means their collectors are also limited. However, since most relays engage at 70% I don't foresee a problem. The relay should engage with this circuit (and the BJTs should share the load to a fair degree.)

Comment: What's the purpose of R14? Pulldown resistors like that I usually see used with FETs, not BJTs. Also, might be a good idea to put a flyback diode on that relay, though I would assume the BC547s can probably handle the spike. It's just good practice.

Comment: @Heath I added it because the OP said they'd used one and because it didn't hurt. BJTs don't really need one for this circuit. The relay won't turn on from static charge like a FET might. But it was harmless. Should I remove it as confusing? I like the addition of the diode. I simply forgot, is all. I'm away from a PC right now, but can address it later when I get a chance.

Comment: @Hearth Got to a PC, so added what I forgot to add. Thanks for the clue!

Comment: I don't see any reason to remove the resistor, I was just wondering what its purpose was. Shouldn't do anything positive or negative there.

Comment: @jonk What is R15 and D21 for? and what does D21 hook to? one end goes to the 6.8 ohm resistor but the other end goes to the 3.3v output on the MCU?

I know you said it's optional, but if it's better for the circuit to have it then I should probably add it. I ordered the 1N4148 anyway after I saw it on there. I just didn't know what it's purpose was so I was curious. (well, i think, i know the diode is to protect against reverse polarity, but i meant the whole thing. resistor, diode, and hooking to 3.3v) Thanks!

Comment: is it just so that it can charge the base to feed the base on Q1?

Comment: @TravisBallard \$R_{15}\$ and \$D_{21}\$ are there to snub the stored energy in the relay coil when you direct that the relay should be turned off. While it is on, current is flowing through the coil and creates a magnetic field storing energy. When you cut the coil off from its source, the magnetic field ***must*** collapse. It's physics stuff. And in collapsing, that energy has to be dissipated. Those two parts provide an "easy path" for this dissipation and helps to make it more rapid, too. Without at least the diode, it's possible to damage the BJTs when they are *hit*. The resistor helps.

Comment: @TravisBallard \$R_{15}\$ helps to dissipate that stored coil energy more quickly. That's why it's optional. Lots of folks don't worry about it and I can't complain. But I added that resistor to roughly double the speed at which the energy would dissipate. If you don't want it, though, feel free to dump it. It's not required. \$D_{21}\$ doesn't have to be a 1N4148, though. If you have different diodes on hand, chances are they will work okay. Any remaining questions?